# SQL ROW_NUMBER gives error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, rank, row-number

I need to order rows in MySQL and assign a number to each row according to that order. `ORDER BY` is working as intended but not `ROW_NUMBER()`.

This works:

```
USE my_database;
SELECT
    id
    ,volume
    FROM my_table
    ORDER BY volume;
```

This does not work:

```
USE my_database;
SELECT
    id
    ,volume
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY volume)
    FROM my_table
    ORDER BY volume;
```

I get this error message:

> SELECT  id  ,volume  ,ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY volume)  FROM my_table  ORDER BY volume    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY volume)  FROM my_table  ORDER BY vol' at line 4  0.000 sec

What am I doing wrong and how do I make it work?

I also tried `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()` which gives the same problem.

Comment: Looks like duplicate question of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Comment: "MySQL introduced the ROW_NUMBER() function since version 8.0"  (https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/)

Answer (score 4):

There are no such things as `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()` in MySQL. Try the following :

```
USE my_database;
SET @row_number = 0; 
SELECT id
     , volume
     , @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS rank
FROM my_table
ORDER BY volume;
```

Comment: This didn't work but it was close to the solution: SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rank, id, volume . Thanks!

Comment: You have an error in variable name. Use row_number and then use rownumber without underscore.

Comment: Hello from the future.  There IS such a thing a ROW_NUMBER starting in MySQL 8 and I'm on MySQL 14, but I *still* get the same error!

Answer (score 3):

The function ROW_NUMBER() does not exist in MySQL.

However, you can replicate it, possibly: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

> The  row_number is a ranking function that returns a sequential number
>   of a row, starting from 1 for the first row. We often want to use the 
>   row_number function to produce the specific reports we need.
>   Unfortunately, MySQL does not provide  row_number like Microsoft SQL
>   Server and Oracle. However, in MySQL, you can use session variables to
>   emulate the  row_number function.

**example:**

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, firstName, lastName
FROM
    employees
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thank you! The solution was  SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rank, id, volume .

Answer (score 3):

MySQL introduced the ROW_NUMBER() function since version 8.0.